# brew installs latest python3 but python3 not updated?

Tags: python, homebrew

Hello I'm trying to upgrade my python from macos

I enter command 'brew upgrade python3' and it tells me the latest version is installed (Warning: python3 3.9.1_8 already installed)

but then when I type 'python3 -V' it returns 'Python 3.6.1'

and when I try to 'brew link --overwrite python@3.9' the operation proceeds successfully but there is still no change.

What am I missing? Why am I not able to use Python3.9?

Comment: `$ which python3`, `$ brew info python3` — Your PATH is not set up so `python3` resolves to brew’s python3.

Comment: Try the command `which python3` to see where the file actually is. I assume it is an environment PATH issue. Check the environment with `env`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `PATH` variable in your environment is not configured correctly and the shell is finding the wrong python3.

You can check for the path to the current python3 command using:

```
which python3
```

Most likely the output will not be pointing at the brew installation that is usually:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

If that was the case check the PATH variable in your environment using:

```
echo $PATH
```

or:

```
env | grep PATH
```

and check whether `/usr/local/bin` is present in the PATH variable and that it has precedence over the folder where your current python3 is located.

Change it by edited the .profile file in your home directory by adding:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you install and use `pyenv`.  It is somewhat standard way of managing multiple Python versions on your Mac. I have 4 different Python versions, and switch from one to the other with ease.  It can do a lot more than just set your global Python version.  Check it out: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.  It can be installed with `brew install pyenv`.